# How do I modify strings generated by an element.strings method in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, string, beautifulsoup

When there are tags within other tags (e.g., the `<b>` within `<p>`), the **string** element of the parent element is empty, and the **strings** element is a generator which produces all the strings.

```
<html>
<body>
<p> First p <b> First b </b>second part first p</p>
<p> Second p <a> first link</a> second part second p <a> second link</a> third part second p</p> 
</body>
</html>
```

In my code,

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)#text above
ps = soup.find_all('p')
p0 = ps[0]
for s in p0.strings:
    #makes sure that child elements inside <p> tag are skipped
    if s.findParent() == p0:
        s.replace_with('new text')
```

However, when I run this, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#243>", line 1, in <module>
        s.replace_with('new_text')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/element.py", line 211, in replace_with
        my_index = self.parent.index(self)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'
```

The first string of p0 had its text changed, but the last element did not, since an error was thrown. The same thing happens with the second element of `p1 = ps[1]`.  How do I go about modifying each of the **string** elements separately? I want to preserve all of the existing tags.

Comment: What is your desired output for the above input HTML? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This loop is not safe because you are modifying `p0` as you iterate over it

```
for s in p0.strings:
```

One safe way is to make a list to snapshot `p0` before you iterate over it.

```
for s in list(p0.strings):
```